# How create package in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
php artisan workbench vendor/package --resources
```

command is not available in [laravel 5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/976b5fd2bab5baa1289ab65844aea029dc24091b), but how now create package in laravel 5 ?

Comment: The message of the commit you linked to says "**Cleaning up config. Remove workbench.** In prep for workbench being a separate CLI tool." I suppose that separate CLI tool has yet to be written so you will have to wait until that's done. Someone correct me if I'm wrong....

Comment: You are right, I found this https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6584

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an unimplemented feature of an in-development version of the framework

Comment: @MartirosAghajanyan a possible way to develop Laravel packages without workbench (and Zend Framework modules as it happens): http://stackoverflow.com/a/35248279/580651

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The laravel workbench has been renamed in laravel 5 to "Package Development" in the documentation

http://laravel.com/docs/master/packages

Notice that there is no longer a workbench command and you need to create your own package structure, as the Laravel creator want to limit the dependency between created packages and the Laravel framework ([#ref](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/556111657898737665))

---

**UPDATE:** Laravel 5 is now stable and the `illuminate/workbench` package can be used in a laravel 5 application as I suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378460/laravel-5-package-development/28383338#28383338)

Answer (score 19):

Shameless self-promotion, but I've written a post about this called "[Creating Laravel 5 packages for dummies](https://medium.com/@tabacitu/creating-laravel-5-packages-for-dummies-ec6a4ded2e93)" that explains how to create the package, how to put it on GitHub & Packagist and how to push changes/new versions afterwards.

If you're already familiar with creating packages in Laravel 4, the fastest solution I've found was to use this [CLI tool](https://github.com/Jeroen-G/laravel-packager).

Comment: Thats a very nice tutorial and the only way that works with laravel 5.1, since the workbench is now completely deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, these are some handy tricks I follow each time I need to create a Laravel package

- **Solution 1**: Get a boilerplate template from https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel5-package-template, and put it under `packages/` (follow the instruction in the repo)
- **Solution 2**: Use a packager (with Laravel >= 5.5)

  - Install packager it as dev dependency > `composer require jeroen-g/laravel-packager --dev` (check instruction in the repo [here](https://github.com/Jeroen-G/laravel-packager))
  - create the package > `composer require jeroen-g/laravel-packager --dev` etc, see [full tuto](https://medium.com/@ajtech.mubasheer/creating-a-package-in-laravel-5-8-49adbb49daca)
  - then, we have a choice to keep the package in our project, or just remove it by rollingback `composer.json`

Hope this is a good update for Laravel lovers ;)