# Laravel 5 package development

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having trouble to create package in Laravel 5 as `workbench` has been removed.

As in this thread ([How create package in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661322/how-create-package-in-laravel-5)), Goldorak suggest that we have to create our own package structure ourselves.

So, how can I create the workbench manually and get everything ready for package development?

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661322/how-create-package-in-laravel-5

Comment: @MartirosAghajanyan That post does not answer my questions. That's why I am asking it here, as you can see I am pointing link to that post. My asking here is how to manually create those file structure (how the structure should be) and get everything ready (all configuration needed to our new file structure) for package development.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

### Using the laravel Workbench package:

You can add the `illuminate/workbench` package in a Laravel 5 by adding to your `composer.json`:

```
"illuminate/workbench": "dev-master"
```

then add the WorkbenchServiceProvider into your `config/app.php` file:

```
'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider'
```

Now you need to create the `config/workbench.php` file since it has been removed from Laravel 5:

```
<?php

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Workbench Author Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When you create new packages via the Artisan "workbench" command your
    | name is needed to generate the composer.json file for your package.
    | You may specify it now so it is used for all of your workbenches.
    |
    */
    'name' => '',
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Workbench Author E-Mail Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Like the option above, your e-mail address is used when generating new
    | workbench packages. The e-mail is placed in your composer.json file
    | automatically after the package is created by the workbench tool.
    |
    */
    'email' => '',
];
```

Fill your information in this config file then you will be able to use the workbench command:

```
php artisan workbench vendor/name
```

---

### Creating your own package structure

In this exemple we will create our package called ***awesome*** in a packages directory.

Here is the package structure:

```
packages/
  vendor/
    awesome/
      src/
        Awesome.php
      composer.json
```

- **Vendor**: your vendor name, typically this is your github username.
- **Awesome**: the name of your package
- **src**: Where you put the business logic

To generate a composer.json file you can use this command in the `packages/vendor/awesome` directory:

```
composer init
```

Now we create a `Awesome.php` class in the `src` directory with a simple method:

```
<?php namespace Vendor/Awesome;

class Awesome
{
    public static function printAwesomeness()
    {
        echo 'Awesome';
    }
}
```

After that we add the package to the laravel `composer.json` psr-4 autoloader:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Vendor\\Awesome\\": "packages/vendor/awesome/src"
    }
},
```

and we dump the composer autoloader

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now you can use your package everywhere in your laravel 5 project. If you need some laravel specific feature like service provider or view publishing, use them as described in the [Laravel 5.0 documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages).

Comment: illuminate/workbench v4.2.1 requires illuminate/support 4.2.*

Comment: I fixed my answer, I tested it on a laravel 5 beta and not stable version, It works on stable now.

Comment: @NicolasBeauvais Thanks a lot for your answer. Seems workbench has been purposely removed, it would be great if package development can be setup without using it.

Comment: @user1995781 In fact you can totaly write a package without workbench. The workbench command just create a directory with some basic files in it but you can do this from scratch. I will update my answer with some explanation on how to write your own package without it.

Comment: @user1995781: The reason for removal was that package development is something that should be framework agnostic so what workbench does should be solved on a PHP level. According to the laravel podcast Taylor Otwell is working on a tool that accomplishes the same as workbench did.

Comment: So I used workbench approach and I can not load my service provider in my L5 config/app.php I get 'not found' error; I am using psr-4 `"Kyslik\\Awesome\\": "workbench/kyslik/awesome/src"` any hints?

Comment: If workbench is removed for the reason @user1995781 stated, does that mean that the above solution is not recommended?

Comment: @Kyslik are your using the correct type case for your directories ? ""Kyslik\\Awesome\\"

Comment: @NicolasBeauvais Yes (everything is correct) and I found solution, my problem is that when I run `composer dump-autoload` it crashes when I load page and L5 can not find my Service Provider, when I run `composer dump-autoload -o` it works like charm. Do you know what causes this behaviour?

Comment: @user1781041 The workbench aproche is a simple way to create a new package and test it in your current Laravel application. The workbench command generate only one Laravel specific file: the ServiceProvider. If you remove it you can create a agnostic package. Or you can use the second method I provided to create your package from scratch.

Comment: @NicolasBeauvais can you write me exactly example of your namespacing? I mean would you use `namespace Kyslik\Awesome` or `namespace \Kyslik\Awesome`.

Comment: Is a workbench equal to a vendor/* ? If I were to create a package that I would like to share so other developers could just include it in the `require-dev` on their composer.json and run composer -update, is this what I should suppose to do in order to create one?

Comment: If you use the workbench command, the generated sample package come  with a composer.json file, this is all you need to share your package

Comment: I notice that when I just simply create a package/myvendorname/mypackagename/* then on the package controller file I namespace it to myvendorname\mypackagename use that on my main controller under app/http/controllers, it can be used already. Now I wonder, what is the purpose of autoloading it on the composer file, adding a service provider, etc if I can just simply include `use mypackagename\myvendorname\mypackagecontroller` and use it with `new mypackagecontroller()` on my app/http/controllers/mycontroller.php file?

Comment: it's give me error : Class 'Vendor\awesome\Controller' not found

Comment: Should there be a 'composer update' command somewhere in there?

Comment: A simple example controller of how to access the package would be useful. May seem easy for some but would complete the answer.

Comment: Can you please provice an example on how to call the class?

Comment: I got an error saying: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. After following your fist step.

Comment: @MaXi32 you would have to lower the `minimum-stability` in `composer.json` which is not really recommended I guess. As mentioned in other answers - here's a non-workbench solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35248279/580651

Answer (score 10):

**laravel 5 Standards with out workbench**.

Set 1 : install laravel as usual.

Step 2 : Create package folder and service provider

In root directory create a folder call "packages" `/"vendorName"/"packageName"/src" Eg: root/packages/jai/Contact/src`

now navigate to src folder and create a service provider class: "ContactServiceprovider.php"

your service provider should extend ServiceProvider which has to implement register method.

Note:If you want you can have dd("testing"); in boot function and go to step 3 but you have copied the file you might want to create views , routes , config and controllers check link below for that

Step 3 : add package path in root `composer.json` in your root composer.json file `"jai\Contact\": "packages/jai/Contact/src/"` under psr-4

```
"psr-4": { "App\": "app/", "Jai\Contact\": "packages/jai/contact/src/", }
```

Step 4 : add service provider in app config.

in your root/conifg/app.php under providers add your package service provider to hook your package in.

```
   'Jai\Contact\ContactServiceProvider',
```

Step 5 : run composer dump-autoload - make sure there are no errors.

all done - now you can access your package via url - `"yourwebsite/contact"`

Resource from here : https://github.com/jaiwalker/setup-laravel5-package

Comment: I followed 3 times. Doesn't work. Keep saying: FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Jai\Contact\ContactServiceProvider' not found

Comment: which Laravel version are you usign this  on ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use package on this named [packman](https://github.com/hadefication/packman). `composer global require "hadefication/packman"`, just a simple package creator for Laravel.