# Laravel 5 FatalErrorException with a provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I configured my config/app.php file and I added this provider:

```
'providers' => [
/*
  Foti Services Providers
*/
 Foticos\LaravelFotiServices\LaravelFotiServicesProvider::class,
],
```

I have created and added namespace to my LaravelFotiServicesProvider file:

```
<?php 

namespace Foticos\LaravelFotiServices;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class LaravelFotiServicesProvider extends ServiceProvider {
...
```

But Laravel 5 reports me this error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Foticos\LaravelFotiServices\LaravelFotiServicesProvider' not found
```

What´s the problem?

Comment: what is the path of the file `LaravelFotiServices`?

Comment: vendor/foticos/laravel_foti_services/src/LaravelFotiServicesProvider.php

Answer (score 2):

As you have placed your files inside the `vendor` folder, you should provide a directive in `composer.json` to let Laravel find your classes. But, be ware that placing your own files inside the `vendor` folder is not a good idea as it's usually used for third party libraries

You should place your source files inside the `app` folder, and they will be automatically PSR-4 namespaced under the namespace `App` because in  `composer.json` is specified:

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
```

So, if you create a subfolder: `app/Libs/Foticos/` the files inside the folder will have the `App\Libs\Foticos` namespace

Instead, if you want to create a package (to use the sources in more than one project, or to re-distribuite them) , check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378460/laravel-5-package-development) to see how you should structure your folders for package-development

**EDIT**

If you absolutely want to leave your folder in `vendor`, try to add this to composer.json:

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Foticos\\": "vendor/foticos/laravel_foti_services/src/" 
    }
```

Then place the file in:

`vendor/foticos/laravel_foti_services/src/LaravelFotiServices/LaravelFotiServicesProvider.php`

And do: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Mmmm, I want to leave my folder in /vendor, what´s the name of the directive? I want place it in composer.json and run the composer update command.

Comment: have you launched `composer dump-autoload` ?